Login issue with Active Directory on Ubuntu via XRDP
I can log in locally with both Active Directory and local users. However, XRDP only allows local user logins and gives an error for Active Directory users.
Error:
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
login failed for display 0
Question: Is there a difference in XRDP handling for local vs. remotely stored users (sssd-ad/Active Directory)? And if so can I get around it to make it work?


We are assuming that you are using sssd for active directory integration and authentication.  To login in AD through xRDP, you need to perform some additional configuration in the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf file.
The easiest way to get xrdp and AD working,  you will need to replace the line
in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
access_provider = ad 
by 
access_provider = simple 

then restart the sssd service
sudo systemctl restart sssd.service 

Try again to perform a remote session and this should be working...
Note : There other possible configuration when speaking about xRDP and Active directory.
We have provided additional info in our blog.  If you want to have more info and confirm that this process is working, you can have a quick look at

XRDP – Ubuntu Active Directory Authentication & xRDP – Overview

xRDP – Remote Connection to Ubuntu Using Active Directory
Authentication (HowTo)


These links are provided for your convenience only and for your information
Hope this help
